# Unable to render a child component inside main Component using iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a main component defined as App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Component } from "react";

import Item from "./components/Item";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { textInput: "", items: [] };
  }
  insertItem() {
    if (this.state.textInput !== "") {
      this.setState((state) => {
        const list = state.items.push(state.textInput);
        return {
          items: list,
          textInput: ""
        };
      });
    }
  }
  deleteItem(index) {
    this.setState((state) => {
      const list = [...state.items];
      list.splice(index, 1);
      return {
        items: list,
        textInput: ""
      };
    });
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ textInput: event.target.value });
  }
  render() {
    const template = (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.textInput}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
          />
          <button onClick={this.insertItem.bind(this)}>Add</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.state.items.map((item, idx) => {
            return <Item name={item} removeItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this, idx)} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    return template;
  }
}
export default App;
```

and a child Component defined in Item.js

```
import { Component } from "react";
class Item extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{this.props.name}</span>
        <span onClick={this.props.removeItem}>X</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Item;
```

Now my UI looks like[image]

In the above code(App.js) Iam trying to iterate the items and then display the names using the child component. But due to some reason, on entering the text in the input and clicking add its not showing up. Also there are no errors in the console.

Please help, thanks in advance

Edited:

After the recent changes I get this error
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have done a few changes in insertItem() and deleteItem()...please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to call `this.deleteItem(idx)` while passing it to the child.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Component } from "react";

import Item from "./components/Item";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { textInput: "", items: [] };
  }
  insertItem() {
    if (this.state.textInput !== "") {
      this.setState((state) => {
        const list = state.items.push(state.textInput);
        return {
          items: list,
          textInput: ""
        };
      });
    }
  }
  deleteItem(index) {
    this.setState((state) => {
      const list = state.items.splice(index, 1);
      return {
        items: list,
        textInput: ""
      };
    });
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ textInput: event.target.value });
  }
  render() {
    const template = (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.textInput}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
          />
          <button onClick={this.insertItem.bind(this)}>Add</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.state.items.map((item, idx) => {
            return <Item name={item} removeItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this, idx)} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    return template;
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating state in react requires a new reference to objects.You're using `Array#push`. It will not detect your new change and the DOM will not update. You need to return a new reference.

```js
  insertItem() {
    if (this.textInput === "") {
      this.setState((state) => {
        // const list = state.items.push(state.textInput);
        const list = [...state.items, state.textInput];
        return {
          list,
          textInput: ""
        };
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not necessarily true. That's only if you don't use the key on the children.

Comment: @MarioVernari Yes, it is true. Keys only suppress unnecessary operations in a render cycle. If you've mutated an array in `state` and still had the DOM update, it's because some other state or prop updated the DOM. It would have been updated by coincidence.  https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

Answer (score 1):

In order to track the array, you must add the `key` attribute:

```
      {this.state.items.map((item, idx) => {
        return <Item key={idx} name={item} removeItem={this.deleteItem(idx)} />;
      })}
```

Here I used the index, but it would be better to use some ID of your model.

UPDATE:

I'd move the handler binding in the constructor:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { textInput: "", items: [] };
    this.insertItem = this.insertItem.bind(this);
  }
```

Then:

```
  <button onClick={this.insertItem}>Add</button>
```

UPDATE 2:

Okay, it seems you have several mistakes (and I didn't notice them at first glance).

Here is the complete working source (tested):

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { textInput: "", items: [] };
  }
  insertItem() {
    if (this.state.textInput !== "") {
      this.setState((state) => {
        //const list = state.items.push(state.textInput);
        const list = [...state.items, state.textInput];
        return {
          items: list,
          textInput: ""
        };
      });
    }
  }
  deleteItem(index) {
    this.setState((state) => {
      const list = [...state.items];
      list.splice(index, 1);
      return {
        items: list,
        textInput: ""
      };
    });
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ textInput: event.target.value });
  }
  render() {
    const template = (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.textInput}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
          />
          <button onClick={this.insertItem.bind(this)}>Add</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.state.items.map((item, idx) => {
            return <Item key={idx} name={item} removeItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this, idx)} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    return template;
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I tried and but still getting this error...Please check the screenshot in the qsn

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move display of template into return statement rather than inside render

```
...
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.textInput}
          onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
        />
        <button onClick={this.insertItem.bind(this)}>Add</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {this.state.items.map((item, idx) => {
          return <Item name={item} removeItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this, idx)} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```